# Retrieving hidden variable value using mootools

Tags: mootools

in my jsp, there's a hidden input variable like this:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="servtype" id="serv_Type" value=noneFiOS TV>
```

I used the below code in mootools to retrieve the value:

```
 var servtype = $("serv_Type").value;
 alert(servtype);
```

The alert is showing only **"noneFiOS"** and not **"noneFiOS TV"** . What's the problem here. Any one pls provide solution to retrieve the whole value including spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the value in quotes:

`<input type="hidden" name="servtype" id="serv_Type" value="noneFiOS TV">`